# Storing values of numpy array in pixels of jpg image

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, image-segmentation

I'm work on an image segmentation problem and have created masks for training. I'm storing those masks in numpy array(values are 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5). I tried exporting them in .npy format but the size is very large and when I'm using matplolib to store these values in jpg, the mask gets disrupted. How can I directly put these numpy array values as pixel values in an image. For example, the numpy array is 300X300 hence the resulting jpg image has resolution 300X300 pixels.

Comment: not sure it's the best tool for this job but you can save compressed arrays with `np.savez_compressed`. You certainly don't want to save your masks in a lossy format like jpg, if you need them to be images maybe png would be better

Comment: My main problem is the size. With numpy for just 1800 masks the size of .npy file is 2GB.

Comment: what about the npz solution I suggested? gave it a try?

Comment: Yeah, it reduced the size significantly. I think this is good.

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas herefore... you could save some space casting your classes into integers so:

```
1.5 -> 1
2 -> 2
2.5 -> 3
...
```

that should also save some space when you use `.npy` format (what i would recommend).
When you need a `png` for visual inspection for instance then use:

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.image.imsave('test.png',pixel_values)
```

and you can make sure in the picture properties that the number of pixels matches the one of the`pixel_value here` matrix.